# MySQL dump to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: mysql, sql

I recently redid a project for my company, and have to convert existing MySQL data to a SLQ Server 2008 R2 database.

I have a dump script from the old MySQL database, but it contains a helluva lot of data.

I was wondering if there are any solutions out there to feed the dump file to, and receive a SQL Server 2008 R2 script.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft provides a free migration solution you maybe want to use

[Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx?q=SSMA) (SSMA)

> The free Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) makes it easy to migrate data from Oracle, Microsoft Access, MySQL, and Sybase to SQL Server. SSMA converts the database objects to SQL Server database objects, loads those objects into SQL Server, migrates data to SQL Server, and then validates the migration of code and data.

Comment: The new link is pointing to the Blog of the SSMA Team. Is that intended? The download is found here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28764

Comment: thanks @Sandro i was confused where is the exact link in these blogs

Comment: I am using an express edition of SQL server 2008 R2, and so have no SQL server agent which is required by SSMA. Therefore this option is not for me.

Comment: It says that my ODBC driver - `MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver (v5.3.4) 32-bit` - is not compatible with the current version of SSMA, even though I installed SSMA for MySQL v5.x. Any ideas?

What I really need is just a way to convert the schema, and more specifically, just the views from the MySQL database to SQL server syntax.